# Why can't I go back to a previously viewed page in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to know why when a open a page (`a1`) in my shiny app and then I open another page (for example `a2`) then I can't come back to `a1`?

To reproduce my example please follow these steps:

1. click on `a2`
2. click on `b1`
3. click on `c1`
4. click on `c8`
5. click on `c1` again

I would expect to see the content of `c1` again ("example of text 2"), but clicking `c1` again appears to do nothing.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  tags$head(tags$style(
    HTML('.content-wrapper { height: 1500px !important;}')
  )),
  hr(),
  sidebarMenu(
    id = "tabs",
    menuItem(
      "a1",
      tabName = "principal",
      icon = icon("pagelines"),
      selected = TRUE
    ),
    menuItem(
      "a2",
      icon = icon("chart-bar"),
      menuSubItem("b1", tabName = "identificacion", icon = icon("angle-right")),
      menuSubItem("b2", tabName = "comunicacion", icon = icon("angle-right")),
      menuSubItem("b3", tabName = "medicamentos", icon = icon("angle-right")),
      menuSubItem("b4", tabName = "cirugias", icon = icon("angle-right")),
      menuSubItem("b5", tabName = "infecciones", icon = icon("angle-right")),
      menuSubItem("b6", tabName = "caidas", icon = icon("angle-right"))
    ),
    menuItem("a3", tabName = "procesos", icon = icon("chart-bar")),
    menuItem("a4", tabName = "tiempos", icon = icon("chart-bar")),
    menuItem("a5", tabName = "manual", icon = icon("mortar-board")),
    menuItem("a6", tabName = "acerca", icon = icon("question"))
  ),
  width = 285,
  hr(),
  conditionalPanel("input.tabs=='identificacion'",
                   fluidRow(
                     column(1),
                     column(
                       10,
                       menuItem(
                         "c1",
                         tabName = "admision_iden",
                         icon = icon("chart-line"),
                         selected = FALSE
                       ),
                       menuItem(
                         "c8",
                         tabName = "uci_iden",
                         icon = icon("chart-line"),
                         selected = FALSE
                       )
                     )
                   ))
)

body <- dashboardBody(tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "principal",
          withMathJax(), ("example of text")),

  tabItem(tabName = "admision_iden", titlePanel("example1"), "example of text 2"),

  tabItem(tabName = "uci_iden", titlePanel("example 2"), "example of text 3")
))

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Indic", titleWidth = 285),
                    sidebar,
                    body)

server <- function(input, output) {}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your additional menus are rendered outside `sidebarMenu`, so when selected, their `id`s are not recorded in the input variable `input$tabs` (which is what the app is monitoring). Including the menus inside `sidebarMenu` allows the `tabItems` to track the `menuItems`, but also breaks the reactivity, i.e., when `input$tabs == 'uci_iden'` the additional menus disappear (because `input$tabs != 'identificacion'`).

---

One way to achieve the behavior you want (possibly not the best way) is to render the additional menus through the `server` using `renderUI`. Note that we still have to include the additional menus inside `sidebarMenu` and monitor them through `input$tabs`. To make sure they stick around when `input$tabs != 'identificacion'`, we can include their `id`s in the condition. When neither of `identification`, `uni_iden` or `admision_iden` are selected, we render an empty `div`.

---

### [image]

Updated code:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  tags$head(tags$style(
    HTML('.content-wrapper { height: 1500px !important;}')
  )),
  hr(),
  sidebarMenu(
    id = "tabs",
    menuItem(
      "a1",
      tabName = "principal",
      icon = icon("pagelines"),
      selected = TRUE
    ),
    menuItem(
      "a2",
      icon = icon("chart-bar"),
      menuSubItem("b1", tabName = "identificacion", icon = icon("angle-right")),
      menuSubItem("b2", tabName = "comunicacion", icon = icon("angle-right")),
      menuSubItem("b3", tabName = "medicamentos", icon = icon("angle-right")),
      menuSubItem("b4", tabName = "cirugias", icon = icon("angle-right")),
      menuSubItem("b5", tabName = "infecciones", icon = icon("angle-right")),
      menuSubItem("b6", tabName = "caidas", icon = icon("angle-right"))
    ),
    menuItem("a3", tabName = "procesos", icon = icon("chart-bar")),
    menuItem("a4", tabName = "tiempos", icon = icon("chart-bar")),
    menuItem("a5", tabName = "manual", icon = icon("mortar-board")),
    menuItem("a6", tabName = "acerca", icon = icon("question")),
  width = 285,
  hr(),
  uiOutput("more_menus")
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "principal",
          withMathJax(), ("example of text")),

  tabItem(tabName = "admision_iden", titlePanel("example1"), "example of text 2"),

  tabItem(tabName = "uci_iden", titlePanel("example 2"), "example of text 3")
))

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Indic", titleWidth = 285),
                    sidebar,
                    body)

server <- function(input, output) {

  make_menus <- reactive({
    if (req(input$tabs) %in% c("identificacion", "admision_iden", "uci_iden")) {
      fluidRow(column(1),
               column(
                 10,
                 menuItem(
                   "c1",
                   tabName = "admision_iden",
                   icon = icon("chart-line"),
                   selected = FALSE
                 ),
                 menuItem(
                   "c8",
                   tabName = "uci_iden",
                   icon = icon("chart-line"),
                   selected = FALSE
                 )
               ))
    } else {
      div()
    }
  })
  output$more_menus <- renderUI({ make_menus() })
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```